# Show that $\int_{-1}^1 \frac{\cos(j \arccos(x)) \cos(k \arccos(x))}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}dx = c_k\delta_{jk}, c_0=\pi, c_k = \pi/2$

Tags: integration

Show that $\int_{-1}^1 \frac{\cos(j \arccos(x)) \cos(k \arccos(x))}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}dx = c_k\delta_{jk}, c_0=\pi, c_k = \pi/2$

I don't know where to start, I suppose you need a clever variable substitution, can anybody give a hint please?

Comment: the searched result should be $$\frac{j \sin (\pi  j) \cos (\pi  k)-k \cos (\pi  j) \sin (\pi  k)}{j^2-k^2}$$

Comment: I suggest that you read about [Chebyshev polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_polynomials).

Answer (score 1):

Use the substitution $y = \arccos (x)$. The denominator is proportional to $dy$.

After that, the integral will transform into the orthogonality condition of cosines that will give you the Kronecker's delta.

Answer (score 0):

Call $u = \arccos x$, such that

$$
{\rm d u} = -\frac{1}{\sqrt{1 - x^2}}{\rm d}x
$$

Therefore

\begin{eqnarray}
I &=& \int_{-1}^{1}{\rm d}x \frac{\cos(j \arccos x) \cos(k \arccos x)}{\sqrt{1 - x^2}} = \int_{0}^{\pi}{\rm d}u \cos (ju) \cos(ku) \\ &=& \frac{1}{2} \int_0^\pi{\rm d}u [\cos(j + k)u + \cos(j - k)u]
\end{eqnarray}

Now three cases

> $j \not= k$

$$
I = \left.\frac{1}{2(j + k)}\sin (j + k)u\right|_0^\pi + \left.\frac{1}{2(j - k)}\sin (j - k)u\right|_0^\pi = 0 \tag{1}
$$

> $j = k$, $j\not = 0$

$$
I = \left.\frac{1}{4j}\sin 2ju\right|_0^\pi + \frac{\pi}{2} \tag{2}
$$

> $j = k$, $j\not \not= 0$

$$
I = \pi \tag{3}
$$

Putting together (1), (2) and (2):

$$
I = \int_{-1}^{1}{\rm d}x \frac{\cos(j \arccos x) \cos(k \arccos x)}{\sqrt{1 - x^2}} = c_k\frac{\pi}{2}
$$

with

$$
c_0 = \pi ~~~\mbox{and}~~~ c_k = \pi\frac{\delta_{jk}}{2}, ~k\not = 0
$$